# Appium inspector on real device - iOS

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, appium

I am evaluvating Appium for my iOS automation testing. As a part of that, I am able to successfully execute appium element inspector when I choose my device target as iPhone simulator. But I am not able to invoke element inspector when I target real device.

I have signed my app with a development provisioning profile and I am able to install and run my app from Xcode 5. So my app setup looks okay as I am able to run my application.

Then I configured all the details in Appium.app GUI like bundle id, device etc... and started the appium server and inspector. When inspector is launched, my app is opened successfully in device but it is not doing any further action and after few seconds, I get a pop as "Please make sure appium server is running and APP_PATH is setup currently......."

I invoked some debugging logs and I am not able to figure out what is the issue from logs. Attaching logs

```
info: Welcome to Appium v1.2.0 (REV e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5)

debug: Non-default server args: {"app":"com.bharathapp.npuzzle","udid":"a3c3ccbed22942bd7866cbf3751363004acec0a8","address":"127.0.0.1","sessionOverride":true,"fullReset":true,"deviceName":"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)","orientation":"Portrait","showSimulatorLog":true,"defaultCommandTimeout":7200}

info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
info: LogLevel: debug

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status

debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 7.573 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.758 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}}}

debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}}}

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}}}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/sessions
debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session
debug: Request received with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"7.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)"}}
debug: App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
debug: Creating new appium session c8bdf0b6-ee57-47ce-ac74-da6ef6d01a27
debug: Removing any remaining instruments sockets
debug: Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
debug: Cleaning up any tracedirs
debug: No tracedirs to clean up
debug: Setting Xcode folder
debug: Setting Xcode version
debug: Setting iOS SDK Version
debug: iOS SDK Version set to 7.1
debug: Detecting automation tracetemplate
debug: Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
debug: Localizable.strings is not currently supported when using real devices.
debug: Not setting locale because we're using a real device
debug: Creating instruments
debug: Preparing uiauto bootstrap
debug: Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
debug: Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js"}
debug: Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!

#import "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/uiauto/bootstrap.js";

bootstrap({
  nodePath: "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node",
  commandProxyClientPath: "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js",
});
debug: Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-fe8fa37a970f98cc.js
debug: Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-fe8fa37a970f98cc.js
debug: Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
debug: Starting iOS device log capture via idevicesyslog
debug: Not setting device type since we're connected to a device
debug: Real device specified but no ipa or app path, assuming bundle ID is on device
debug: Starting command proxy.
debug: Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
debug: Starting instruments
debug: Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
debug: Attempting to run app on real device with UDID a3c3ccbed22942bd7866cbf3751363004acec0a8
debug: Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -w a3c3ccbed22942bd7866cbf3751363004acec0a8 com.bharathapp.npuzzle -e UIASCRIPT /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-fe8fa37a970f98cc.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
debug: And extra without-delay env: {}
debug: And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:15 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Warning>: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.filebrowser
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.234 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 15.674 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"7.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)"}}
info: Launching instruments
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.998 ms - 155 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}},"sessionId":"c8bdf0b6-ee57-47ce-ac74-da6ef6d01a27"}
warn: Instruments socket client never checked in; timing out (global)
info: Launching instruments
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms - - 


debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:15 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Warning>: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.launchdaemon
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:15 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Warning>: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:16 Bharath kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[10422] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/A264164B-EEDE-43CF-80AF-6972D5C0E829 (sandbox)
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:16 Bharath backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'npuzzle' access to protected services is denied.
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:16 Bharath networkd[82] <Warning>: Analytics Engine: double ON for app: com.bharathapp.npuzzle
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:17 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Warning>: CLTilesManagerClient: initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:17 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Warning>: CLTilesManagerClient: init
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:17 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Warning>: CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting, 0x15d914b0
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:17 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Warning>: [AppDeveloper] Fill rate for development application 'com.bharathapp.npuzzle': 80.0%
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:17 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Error>: CoreLocation: could not chmod /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.CoreMotion.plist errno 2 (No such file or directory)
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:17 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Error>: CoreLocation: could not chown /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.CoreMotion.plist errno 2 (No such file or directory)
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:17 Bharath DTMobileIS[10421] <Warning>: -[UIAutomationService _startUpAgent]: posix_spawn(): Resource temporarily unavailable
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:35 Bharath lockdownd[52] <Notice>: 00281000 _select_socket: receive secure message timeout!
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:35:35 Bharath lockdownd[52] <Notice>: 00281000 _receive_message: walk away - non-SSL 1
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:06 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Warning>: [AppDeveloper] Fill rate for development application 'com.bharathapp.npuzzle': 80.0%
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:06 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Warning>: [AppDeveloper] Simulating an inventory-unavailable server response due to development application fill rate. To change the fill rate, see the Developer panel in Settings.
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:06 Bharath npuzzle[10422] <Warning>: The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status
debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}},"sessionId":"c8bdf0b6-ee57-47ce-ac74-da6ef6d01a27"}
debug: Killall instruments
debug: [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code null
debug: Killall instruments
debug: Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
debug: Killall iPhoneSimulator
debug: Attempting to run app on real device with UDID a3c3ccbed22942bd7866cbf3751363004acec0a8
debug: Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -w a3c3ccbed22942bd7866cbf3751363004acec0a8 com.bharathapp.npuzzle -e UIASCRIPT /Users/BharathMBA/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-fe8fa37a970f98cc.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
debug: And extra without-delay env: {}
debug: An
d launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:50 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Warning>: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.filebrowser
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:50 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Warning>: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.launchdaemon
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:50 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Warning>: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:51 Bharath com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.bharathapp.npuzzle[0x3713][10422]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.bharathapp.npuzzle[0x3713]) Exited: Killed: 9
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:51 Bharath backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.bharathapp.npuzzle[0x3713]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:51 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Warning>: tcp_connection_set_source_application proc_pidinfo PROC_PIDUNIQIDENTIFIERINFO for pid 10422 failed
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:51 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Error>: tcp_connection_host_start 8 DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: -65555
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:52 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Warning>: tcp_connection_set_source_application proc_pidinfo PROC_PIDUNIQIDENTIFIERINFO for pid 10422 failed
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:52 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Error>: tcp_connection_host_start 11 DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: -65555
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[10424] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/A264164B-EEDE-43CF-80AF-6972D5C0E829 (sandbox)
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'npuzzle' access to protected services is denied.
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Warning>: CLTilesManagerClient: initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Warning>: CLTilesManagerClient: init
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Warning>: CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting, 0x1656a780
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Warning>: [AppDeveloper] Fill rate for development application 'com.bharathapp.npuzzle': 80.0%
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath AdSheet[10418] <Warning>: [AppDeveloper] Simulating an inventory-unavailable server response due to development application fill rate. To change the fill rate, see the Developer panel in Settings.
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath npuzzle[10424] <Warning>: The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Error>: CoreLocation: could not chmod /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.CoreMotion.plist errno 2 (No such file or directory)
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Error>: CoreLocation: could not chown /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.CoreMotion.plist errno 2 (No such file or directory)
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:53 Bharath DTMobileIS[10423] <Warning>: -[UIAutomationService _startUpAgent]: posix_spawn(): Resource temporarily unavailable
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:36:54 Bharath npuzzle[10424] <Warning>: The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:37:10 Bharath lockdownd[52] <Notice>: 00281000 _select_socket: receive secure message timeout!
debug: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Aug 14 09:37:10 Bharath lockdownd[52] <Notice>: 00281000 _receive_message: walk away - non-SSL 1

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.278 ms - 155 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}},"sessionId":"c8bdf0b6-ee57-47ce-ac74-da6ef6d01a27"}

debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.0","revision":"e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5"}},"sessionId":"c8bdf0b6-ee57-47ce-ac74-da6ef6d01a27"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're getting the log:**

> *"Real device specified but no ipa or app path, assuming bundle ID is on device"*

When I try to run the inspector without the app path, I get the error:

> *...running with an application opened by using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app ...or by connecting with selenium client and supplying this in the desired capabilities object.*

**Try This:**

> - Archive a build in Xcode, then copy the .app file that's generated into a relevant directory.
> - Copy the path of the .app file into the 'app path' configuration.
> - **Run It**

Comment: where is the app path configuration?

Comment: @RameshSangili If you're using the Appium gui, then click the apple button (which brings up the iOS capabilities). The line that says app path, put the file path (path/to/my/.app). Or, if you're stating the capabilities in your code, then see the server arguments on the appium website (http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#appium-server-arguments).